# How to find / \ (slashes) in a text file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file a.txt and I want to find slashes(/ and \ ) in it, so I used this command in my a.ksh script slashcheck=`cat a.txt | grep '/'`.

but how do I check for '' backward slash at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this: `cat a.txt | grep "[\/]"`

Comment: Are you sure this works and finds both forward and backward slashes?

Comment: I'll be, I just tested it and it actually does. Sorry for doubting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression.
You could use something like `grep -E '[/\\]'`.

Note that you will need two backslashes because the first one masks the second one.

Using squared brackets allows any character in these brackets to be a match.

The `-E` stands for extended and allows regular expressions to be used as seach patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

`cat a.txt | egrep '(\/|\\)'`